# Problems importing a package

Tags: import

Has anyone else encountered this problem when importing a function from a package, it does so on a new line and not on the same line that already exists?

Attached is an image of what happens to me when I use the import suggestion

```js
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { object } from 'zod'
import { string } from 'zod'
```

As you can see I import several react hooks and the import is separated and not in the same line, the same happens when importing zod

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, when asking a question about code, the very first tag you add should be for the language you're using.

Comment: Sorry I did not know, thank you for informing me

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
```

You can just re-write it so everything from the same resource can be imported together.